# Should I flag obvious mistakes that are pointed out by the asker in an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

I am reviewing the answer (by OP) to the following question in the Low Quality Posts review queue

- [AngularJS Jasmine comparing arrays returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966230/angularjs-jasmine-comparing-arrays-returning-error)

It looks like the asker made a simple mistake.  They technically answered their own question, but their mistake was trivial and their answer *could* be interpreted as a comment to the answer above

Should I

1. flag the question and just have it deleted because it's not a valuable programming question? If so, what should I flag it as?
2. recommend deletion of their answer as a comment?
3. take some other clever and insightful action on this question or answer?
4. say it looks ok?

The answer in review looked like:

[image]

Comment: It seems a mod has already dealt with this.

Comment: I use "Off-topic: not reproducable or *a simple typographic error*" for such cases. Those questions are indeed not helpful for others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should you

> flag the question and just have it deleted because it's not a valuable programming question? If so, what should I flag it as?

If it really just was a typographically error, then closevoting it as *Off-Topic: not reproducable or a simple typographic error* would be a valid course of action. However, in this case, it doesn't apply because knowing when to use `toBe` and `toEqual` is a semantical error and not just a typo.

> recommend deletion of their answer as a comment?

No. Answering your own question when you found the solution is fine. It may help future visitors with a similar problem.

> take some other clever and insightful action on this question or answer?

You could downvote it because the OP apparently didn't research what `toEqual()` does *before* s/he asked the question. The OP wrote "I am always getting error that the array content is not equal to my static arr var" which already hints at what the problem might be.

> say it looks ok?

It's trivial and value to future visitors is likely not that high. But apart from maybe downvoting it, nothing needs to be done. It certainly doesn't need moderator attention.

Comment: Was the answer posted after the answer which is now accepted? If so, I don't see why the OP's post should not be deleted.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy no, the accepted answer was posted a minute later.

Comment: Was "a typographically error" intentional?

Comment: @AirThomas I'll just keep pretending it was :)