# Recently flagged an answer as "offensive", it got deleted, but the flag was denied. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, offensive

Earlier, I flagged [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266850/should-i-flag-obvious-mistakes-that-are-pointed-out-by-the-asker-in-an-answer/266970#266970) (Only 10k rep users can see it) as **offensive**. It was downvoted to **-14** and later on, deleted.

> [image]

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: Take into account that 'offensive' carries with it a 100 point penalty and the post contents are used as signal in automated systems. The post was noise, not offensive, so the penalty should not apply, nor should the contents be used as signal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think this should be noted somewhere (next to the **flag as** maybe?). Because I suspect I might not be the only one that didn't know that this flag was **that much** severe.

Comment: I don't quite see how 'watch them burn' is *offensive* though. Note that if 6 people had flagged it as offensive, the post would have been  auto-deleted. Because a moderator declined the flag, we know that it never got that far; not enough people agreed it was *offensive*.

Comment: It was stupid, not offensive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That answer was not offensive, abusive, or hate speech. It was not a viable answer, but the flag does not apply.

Offensive and spam flags can carry heavy penalties, and they create audit cases, so we are conservative on accepting them.

Comment: I understand. So **offensive** and **spam** flags are to use only on extreme cases.. That would have been a case for **Not an answer**?

Comment: @Sifu - "not an answer" would be a good fit, yes. Even for Meta, that was nowhere near an answer.

Comment: Does that mean that ads should not been marked as spam? IMHO im most cases it should been deleted but it might doesn't need to hammer that 100 rep lost.

Answer (score 3):

It was deleted for a reason other than being offensive.  (Namely that it's just useless noise.)