# Comment deleted; what should I have done? Do I have right of reply?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I just had a comment (on an answer) removed, possibly for being offensive, because the person who commented told me that they flagged it as such. I do not have the precise wording of my comment to hand, but the comment I responded to was:

> [some snipped] You could just check it, you know.

I responded by saying that this was *patronising* and suggesting that if the information was known it should just be posted (especially since, in this case, I *had* already "checked it", and doing so yielded no useful information other than confirming what I had already stated).

The response comment was deleted. Other than the reference to the other person being *patronising* I fully believe that it was not offensive, and I would argue further that it is not offensive to call someone out for being *patronising* if you really believe that they were. However, the moderator(s) appear to have taken a different stance.

So, my question is: if someone is mildly offensive (by being patronising or perhaps more accurately condescending) in a comment, what should I do?

- Marking the comment as offensive seems heavy handed
- Letting the patronising comment stand without question on the other hand is not, I feel, something that users should be asked to do.

**Summary of responses:**

My take-away is that all comments should directly contribute to the answer/question that they are posted on. Engaging in unrelated argument doesn't qualify. Any post that is rude should be flagged as such, or with another flag such as "obsolete" or "not constructive" if one of those apply.

I should have:

- flagged the comment that I found offensive
- limited any response to issues related directly to the answer.

Thanks to those who responded.

Comment: It's noise either way....lose it. Don't engage.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, but the "You could just check it" comment is also noise then, right? Should I flag it as offensive?

Comment: Either that or too chatty/not contructive/other...whatever. Once you flagged it...move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if someone is mildly offensive ... what should I do?

Flag the comment as rude/offensive.  Our [Be Nice Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), errs on the side of caution (some less relevant content trimmed out):

> Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.
>
> Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> - Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
> - Harassment and bullying. If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, **disengage** — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

Belittling/patronizing comments are unprofessional and don't have a place on our site. They can and should be flagged as rude/offensive.  Don't get into a comment war with name calling.  Just let the mods handle it and remove the comment.

Alternatively, the comment might also qualify for one of the other flag reasons (like "too chatty") if you feel that maybe it's not actually rude/offensive. For example, many such comments quickly become obsolete or not constructive when the OP makes it clear that information doesn't exist or isn't relevant.

Comment: I've always read on meta that only the worst stuff should be flagged as offensive because of [the -100 rep penalty an offensive flag carries](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267363/recently-flagged-an-answer-as-offensive-it-got-deleted-but-the-flag-was-deni).

Comment: @BSMP [no automatic penalty for offensive comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291391/consequences-for-rude-comment/291392#291392)